# What is an advanced area in football (soccer) field?

Tags: football, terminology

In this article [Tactical Theory: Vertical Build-Up Passing](http://spielverlagerung.com/2016/05/12/tactical-theory-vertical-build-up-passing/)  the author used the words **advanced area** for many times, for example

> Every team utilises different build-up patterns in order to move into more **advanced areas** of the pitch

or

> But midfielders, who have more license to move into **advanced areas**, can combine passing accuracy & aim with runs of their own.

Could you please explain for me what is an advanced area?
I wonder is there an official definition of **advanced area** or it is just the dangerous area in opponent's field?

Answer (score 5):

To advance is to move forward; to be advanced is to have moved, or be in a position which is comparatively, forward of some other place.

In football the primary division of the field is the half, by the centreline. Thus, an *advanced area* is best understood to be one which is forward of the team's own half, i.e. a position in which that team is attacking.